# Country location nexus 7

Tags: android

im building an application that requires the country the user is in. I have no problem getting the country if the user is using a smart phone with

```
telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()
```

but how can I achieve this if they are not using a sim, i.e. a nexus 7???

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Nexus 7 is not a smartphone, and has no capabilities to call or send sms, so I don't think this option is available for that device.

Comment: i know its not a smart phone, i have one...i also know it doesnt have a sim..hence the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in order to check whether the user is on a tablet or on a phone:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager1 = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if(telephonyManager1.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE) {
  // TABLET
}
else {
  // YOUR PREVIOUS CODE
}
```

Maybe you can try with the Locale, if the user is in a tablet? I know this doesn't give you the location, but maybe you can try to find out according to the Locale the user has:

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Locale will not give you current location.

Comment: Don't know who gave you -1, but I haven't said solution is wrong. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain the users location (rough approximation should suffice) and then lookup the approximate address with a Geocoder to determine the country.

In fact, your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296277/android-location-services-determine-country-region-from-user-current-location?) one.

But in Android, you now get the Geocoder built-in, so no need to specially call a webservice and decode json. See the [Location Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html) on how to get the users location and the [Geocoder API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) for how to retrieve the location.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would extend the logic to something like this:

- Use TelephonyManager
- If no modem/SIM is present, [use WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172831/get-location-details-using-wifi)
- If no modem/SIM is present, and WiFi is disabled, [use GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11082738/147407)
- If no modem/SIM is present and both WiFi and GPS are disabled, [use Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getCountry())

This way you would cover as much scenarios as possible.

**NB** Locale will not provide you with your current country, but is dependent on what language is selected in your Android device. I.e., if your phone is in Russian, you will *always* get Russia.

Comment: -1 for suggesting locale as a substitute for location. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7976432/319204

Comment: Oh, really? :-) Please tell me other options then, if a device does not have any possibilities to obtain the location (no modem, no WiFi, no GPS)?

Comment: Updated my answer with a note about using Locale.